# Does LINQPad load entire SQL result set into memory before displaying it?

Tags: linqpad

I'm attempting to use LINQPad as an SSMS replacement, but it takes an inordinate amount of time to return large result sets. I usually give up waiting after a few minutes, but if I leave it alone LINQPad will often time out with an out of memory error.

Does LINQPad load the entire result set into memory before displaying it in the grid? Is it capable of returning records in chunks, adding records to the output grid as more results become available from the database -- similar to the way SSMS works?

Cross-posted (and revised) from the LINQPad formus (http://forum.linqpad.net/discussion/303/is-entire-sql-result-set-loaded-into-memory-before-display) as I haven't had a response there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This shouldn't happen in rich text mode, because LINQPad implicitly limits the amount of data it fetches (by default, 1000 rows). After some investigation, it appears the problem is due to a bug in ADO.NET's SqlDataReader. When you dispose a data reader after reading only a portion of the rows, it "cleans" the reader by enumerating all remaining data. It certainly is annoying, so I'm looking into whether it's possible to detect this condition and cancel the underlying command.

Edit: there's a workaround for this in the latest beta, so in rich text mode, the query should now complete quickly with the first 1000 rows.